# PHP XML Attributes Parsing

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Using the code here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_parser_expat.asp

How would you get the attributes using the switch (if possible) for each one if the XML file was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to id="01">Tove</to>
<from id="02">Jani</from>
<heading color="#CEAF33">Reminder</heading>
<body type="small" important="low">Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use W3's tutorial. I'd use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) to load your string into an XML object, then iterate over it like so:

```
$notes = simplexml_load_string( $xml);
foreach( $notes as $note)
{
    echo $note . "[" . $note->getName() . "]\n";
    foreach( $note->attributes() as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "\t" . $key . '=' . $value . "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AV0QWS) (uses your input string)

Comment: How can I do this with an API that doesn't have a doctype? I want to use W3Schools tutorial, because that's what I've learned from. I have everything almost ready and all I need to do is get the attributes from the API.

Comment: SimpleXML doesn't require an HTML doctype definition, it just needs to be valid XML (i.e. start with a `<?xml ...?>` tag and contain a top level XML node). W3Schools tutorial is cumbersome and inefficient, you should be able to use this in any setup.

Comment: The api I use doesn't have an <?xml ... ?> beginning. How do I validate it? I tried using simplexml_load_file(file.xml,LIBXML_DTDVALID(1)); but it doesn't work. Do I really need to create a XML document using code just to validate it?

Comment: If it's outputting XML, just concatenate a simple `<?xml ?>` tag to the beginning so `simplexml_load_string` works.

Comment: thanks for the example :) I'm going to work it with APIs. It does look a lot simpler. Now I just have to figure out how I can do different things with each element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SimpleXML extension, it is much simpler and easier to work with.

From the PHP docs:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php for more information.

Comment: How can I do this with an API that doesn't have a doctype? I want to use W3Schools tutorial, because that's what I've learned from. I have everything almost ready and all I need to do is get the attributes from the API.

Comment: Here is a guide on dealing with common XML errors. http://au2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php

Comment: Also, I understand that you want to use the W3Schools tutorial, but seriously, it is completely outdated and takes a lot longer to implement. SimpleXML was designed to improve the horrible XML situation we had in PHP.